# Loading a URL in a frame using Selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, frames

I'm trying to load a URL in a frame using the following code, but the URL is just loading in the Main Window.

```
        WebDriver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
        WebDriver.SwitchTo().Frame("mainContent").Navigate().GoToUrl(_baseUrl);
```

Any idea how to load a URL directly into a frame?

Comment: A frame = an iframe. What's the intention behind this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm performing the ExecuteLoad for a page created with page factory page object. The application has a Main Window that contains only navigation and an iframe. The content pages are loaded within "mainContent" iframe. I'm trying to load pages within the iFrame without the need for navigation.

Comment: I think you're going to need to use `JavacriptExecutor` for that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to use the scriptexecutor and a script.
Activate the frame to load by using the driver.

```
//Driver implements IJavaScriptExecutor, like 
// OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriver 
// that inherits OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver 
// which implements implements IJavaScriptExecutor
InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@".");
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

Execute the script that loads the url in the activated frame by using the driver

```
string _baseUrl = "www.google.com";
// the script that should be executed
string javascript = string.Format("window.location.href = \"{0}\";", _baseUrl);
try
{
    driver.ExecuteJavaScript<int>(javascript);
}
catch (NullReferenceException e)
{ //not sure why a null reference exception is thrown}
```

Comment: You should add some explanation to the code in your answer.